# Accessing ASP.NET website from LAN

Tags: asp.net, iis, lan

I have tried to access a website that i created in my xp machine that have iis 5.1 from the LAN , but without any success i have tried what is suggested in the following link [How to access your website through LAN in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646370/how-to-access-your-website-through-lan-in-asp-net) , but also without any clue . I open my site in my PC(locally) like this "192.168.1.252/pse" and it works , but from other pc in the LAN , its not displayed at all.

Any Help will be most appreciated.
Thanks,
Saed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Windows Firewall turned on?

Answer (score 0):

You say, "its not displayed at all". What happens instead of it being displayed? Is there an error message?

Most likely, your firewall software is blocking external access. If external users can find your machine using `ping`, then that suggests a firewall is blocking access.

Answer (score 0):

Please do what the two previous posts suggested, check to see if you can ping your computer from a different computer within the network and then check your firewall also.

When you are done checking the above suggestions, if you still have trouble viewing your page from a different computer, check to see if your computer has **port 80** open. And if it is using port 80 and everything looks ok, please provide the error number you are receveiving, I am guessing it is 404 - Page not found.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It was firewall and Antivirus problem , they were blocking the port 80.

Thanks All for your Help.

Saed