# How to host my webpage in the LAN Network

Tags: asp.net, cassini

Using ASP.Net

Am New to website development

Currently am developing a web pages, when i run the program, the output was displaying in this address "http://localhost:1127/WebSite1/"

I want to host this site in my server (LAN Network),

For Example,

My web page address is webpage1.com

In the LAN Network, In another computer when i give the address like webpage1.com it should appear my developed webpage. when I modified something in my web page, the change should also reflected in webpage1.com

Note: Am not asking host my web page in Internet.

How to give website address like webpage1.com in asp.net and also how to host my webpage in LAN Network.

Please can one give the procedure and Ideas?

Comment: Can someone remove that block of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See following:
[How to access your website through LAN in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646370/how-to-access-your-website-through-lan-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio's web server is by design only accessible via the loop-back/local address. You will have to install IIS and deploy your site there in order to do what you want to do.

Comment: Can you tell the procedure, what are thinks i have to do