# Test Website on Local Network

Tags: ipad, iis, testing

I'm a web developer that's not very savvy when it comes to networking. I have a web site that is on my local machine. I've setup the website so that it is currently running on my local IIS. I can access the website while doing development by putting `http://localhost:11000/` into the address bar of my browser. Now, I want to test my website on a tablet.

My tablet and my local development machine are on the same network. I confirmed they are hitting the same router. When I ask Google what my IP address is, it returns the same address for both my development machine and on my tablet. When I enter [ipAddress]:11000 into the browser on my tablet, it works for a while and then returns nothing. The browser just says:

"Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding."

My question is, how do I test a website from my local development machine on my tablet? Are there IIS settings I need to change? If so, what settings?

Thank you!

iis ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the command window and enter ipconfig to discover the ip address of your dev machine. Then use that IP address on your remote machine (ipad). The IP address you are getting that is the same between your workstation and your ipad is likely your router's address. but each of your devices has an address of its own; you need the workstation's IP address to connect to its IIS instance.

A similar question was answered previously at:

[How to access your website through LAN in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646370/how-to-access-your-website-through-lan-in-asp-net)