# Publishing an asp.net page i made on visual studio on my lan

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

so i ve been experimenting with asp.net c# and i have a really basic page that id like to see on the other pcs in my lan(you can even test it with an hello world page if you want the content isn't relevant for the context) but im really struggling with the publishing through IIS. so im starting to think that im doing something wrong with visual studio. what is the procedure to get a page ready to deploy from the solution i have? i ve been really trying many things([How to access your website through LAN in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646370/how-to-access-your-website-through-lan-in-asp-net/646386) this post made me believe i finally found the solution) but i can't really figure out what is the problem. if i try to connect to my page after i think i have it on LAN i get HTTP 403.14

Comment: Can you get to a plain old HTML page at the desired URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/17631211/395675. Take a look at that and see if it helps.