# Deploying ASPNet core on IIS not working at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I have published an ASP.NET Core application on IIS that won't work.

I followed these steps/tutorial: https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/646386/11498427

So this is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Published the ASP.NET Core application with the file folder publish. Then unzipped it and put the whole folder inside: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\"
Set the appropriate folder's with the full control permissions.
Set the appropriate authentication within IIS manager
Set the appropriate settings for the application pool.
.NET Core Server bundle correctly installed (latest, see screenshot)
[image: .NET Core server versions]

'localhost' working fine. But whenever I try to reach my application it gives me a 404. Anyone knows what could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `web.config` is invalid. Those environment variables must be replaced with valid values, if you check other threads.

Comment: Ehmm, okay. Will try, thanks! @LexLi